# How can I get a QUERY to CONCATENATE text after it combines data?

Tags: google-sheets, concatenation, google-sheets-formula

On this sheet, I've been working on I have the info I need adjusting down into the Query Results

```
=QUERY(Investors!A4:D, 
 "select B,C,sum(D) 
  where B is not null
  group by B,C
  label sum(D)''")
```

How do I get the Stock Numbers Due that day to be listed out in column D? Like this:

```
 1. 10/7/2019   Grady Johnson   $100.12     PT-1013
 2. 11/15/2020  Bill Jones      $553.80     PT-1020, PT-1019
 3. 11/15/2020  Grady Johnson   $45.00      PT-1011
 4. 11/15/2020  Steve Robinson  $320.00     PT-1018, PT-1016
 5. 11/17/2020  Jim Luke        $1,057.20   PT-1009, PT-1008, PT-1007, PT-1006
 6. 11/22/2020  Jim Luke        $300.43     PT-1010
```

Here's the link: [Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sSuHK0h2OeaEJpraoHXTi01XIwpreM47BovQAV-snDE/edit?usp=sharing)

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

or paste this in row 3 and drag down:

```
=JOIN(", ", IFNA(FILTER(Investors!A$4:A, Investors!B$4:B&" "&Investors!C$4:C=A3&" "&B3)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks player0, when this sheet is done I'm going to throw a few dollars your way through PayPal for the help. That's TWO you've helped me with now, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(IFNA(VLOOKUP(TO_TEXT(A3:A)&" "&B3:B, 
 TRIM({TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(QUERY({Investors!A4:C}, 
 "select Col2,Col3,count(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col2,Col3 pivot Col1"), 
 "select Col1,Col2 offset 1", 0)),,9^9)), 
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(QUERY(QUERY({Investors!A4:C}, 
 "select count(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col2,Col3 pivot Col1"), 
 "offset 1", 0)="",,
    QUERY(QUERY({Investors!A4:A&",", Investors!B4:C},
 "select count(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col2,Col3 pivot Col1"), 
 "limit 0", 1))),,9^9))}), 2, 0)), ",$", ))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggested formula to be placed in Combined!D3 of your sample spreadsheet:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(A3:A="",,SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(VLOOKUP(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(Investors!A4:A,Investors!A4:A<>"")),{Investors!A:A,Investors!C:C&Investors!B:B},2,FALSE)=B3:B&A3:A,TRANSPOSE(FILTER(Investors!A4:A,Investors!A4:A<>"")),))," ",COUNTA(Investors!A4:A))))," ",", ")))
```

As for *how* it works, that would be time-consuming to explain. (More time than is reasonable for a free site such as this.) I will suggest that, if this is important to you, take the time to study it. Take it apart and see what each piece does — separately and then in combination with other parts — until you've gotten it all back together.